# 英語が残っている: 質問をSNSでシェアする記述

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

回答がない質問にある、「Share a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook. 」が未翻訳です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

翻訳を更新しておきました。 - https://ja.traducir.win/string/10551
(Google+の文字列が削除されたことで、原文がアップデートされていたようです。)