# 翻訳済みテキストが英語に戻ってしまう

Tags: 機能の要求, 翻訳

サイトのUIやヘルプページ等を随時日本語への翻訳を行っていると思いますが、恐らく原文(英語)が更新されたタイミング等で翻訳済みのテキストが英語に戻されてしまうケースが度々あります。

- [未翻訳：質問一覧の上のカテゴリー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2923/3060)
- [英語が残っている: 質問をSNSでシェアする記述](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2906/3060)

翻訳作業は [traducir](https://ja.traducir.win/) の使用が推奨されていますが、こちらのツールだと翻訳履歴が簡単に確認できません(方法があるのか分からない)。
結局は従来の [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/) を行き来しながら履歴があるのかを確認しつつ再翻訳を行う手間が発生しています。

翻訳作業はボランティアの協力により、少なくない時間をかけて作り上げられているものですので、簡単に結果が失われないような仕組みが欲しいです。

参考までに、他のWeb翻訳ツールなどでは更新があった箇所にはそのことが分かるようにマークが付いたりします。

**追記**

[traducir.win のチャット](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1247/traducir-win) で質問したところ、翻訳がリセットされているわけではなく、原文を変更すると新しい文字列(キー)として登録されるので、対応する翻訳が見つからない状態になる、ということらしいです。
(データベースで言うとupdateの代わりに常にinsertしているようなもの？)

例：

- "Welcome to Stack Overflow" に対して "スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ" と翻訳済み。
- 英語が "Welcome to Stack Overflow!" に変更される。 (文字列自体がキーとなっている)
- 対応する翻訳が見つからなくなるので、結果的に英語のまま表示されるようになってしまう。

Comment: MSEに [international-sites] タグ付きで投稿頂けるとTraducirの開発者に見てもらえるかもしれません。 https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5binternational-sites%5d%20is%3aquestion

Comment: Traducir の issue に編集履歴についてのものがあることを見つけました。まだ open です: https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues/113